Error making appointment: FormatException: Invalid date format in Flutter app using Dio for API requests
I am working on a Flutter application that involves making appointments by selecting a date and time. The appointment details are then sent to the backend via an API request. However, I'm encountering a FormatException: Invalid date format error when I run the app. Below are the relevant parts of my code:
DateTimePicker Screen Function:
Future<void> _makeAppointment() async {
  if (_currentDay != null && _selectedStartTime != null && _selectedEndTime != null) {
    ApiDataService api = ApiDataService();

    String startTimeFormatted = _formatTimeOfDay(_selectedStartTime!);
    String endTimeFormatted = _formatTimeOfDay(_selectedEndTime!);
    Map<String, dynamic> appointmentData = {
      'service_provider_id': widget.serviceProviderId,
      'date': _currentDay.toString().split(' ')[0],
      'start_time': startTimeFormatted,
      'end_time': endTimeFormatted,
    };

    try {
      await api.postAppointment(appointmentData);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => RequestServiceScreen(
            date: _currentDay,
            startTime: _selectedStartTime!,
            endTime: _selectedEndTime!,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error making appointment: $e');
    }
  }
}

ApiDataService Function:
Future<void> postAppointment(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
  try {
    data['start_time'] = DateFormat.Hm().format(DateTime.parse(data['start_time']));
    data['end_time'] = DateFormat.Hm().format(DateTime.parse(data['end_time']));

    final response = await _dio.post('$url/api/schedule', data: data);
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to create appointment');
    }
  } on DioException catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Error: ${e.response?.data}');
  }
}

Backend Function (PHP):
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'service_provider_id' => 'required|exists:service_providers,id',
        'date' => 'required|date',
        'start_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
        'end_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i|after:start_time',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 422);
    }

    ProviderAvailability::create([
        'service_provider_id' => $request->service_provider_id,
        'date' => $request->date,
        'start_time' => $request->start_time,
        'end_time' => $request->end_time
    ]);

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Provider availability created successfully']);
}

Error:
I/flutter ( 5890): Error making appointment: FormatException: Invalid date format

I suspect the issue might be with the time formatting or how the date is being parsed and sent to the backend. I've tried ensuring the time format matches the expected H:i format in the backend validation, but the error persists.
How can I resolve this FormatException and ensure the date and time formats are correctly handled in both the Flutter app and the backend?
Thank you for any help you can provide!

Can you share you start, end date that you are passing
